# Including jQuery Ul widgets. How to include jQuery Ul on localhost?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xampp

I am trying to build jQuery code using local server with XAMPP. The problem is when I try to include jQueryUI. When I open the file in a browser in the standard way it's working fine, but when I open it in localhost it shows me this error:

> GET http://localhost/jQuery_files/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css net::ERR_ABORTED.

What am I missing here, is there any solution?

```
<head>
    <link href="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: why include it in body ? and not in head or after body ?

Comment: have you downloaded the files locally and put them under jquery-ui-1.12.1? If not do that first

Comment: @MihaiT there's benefits to putting script right before the </body> tag, such as it can reduce the time before elements appear in the DOM. It generally depends on how you JS is structured as to what works best. Script should never be placed after the </body>, though

Answer (score 0):

You need to download jquery library file for using it in localhost, or you can include jquery by jquery library 's absolute path.

Reference in here
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp